# Concurrency in Elastic scripted metric aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement an average as a scripted metric aggregation in Elasticsearch. This is what I've come up with:

```
{
  "scripted_metric": {
    "init_script": {
      "source": "state.sum = 0.0; state.count = 0.0;",
      "lang": "painless"
    },
    "map_script": {
      "source": " if (doc.TradedValue.size() > 0) {   state.sum += doc.TradedValue.value;   state.count++; }",
      "lang": "painless"
    },
    "combine_script": {
      "source": "return state;",
      "lang": "painless"
    },
    "reduce_script": {
      "source": " double avg = 0; double c = 0; for (s in states) { avg += s.sum; c += s.count; }  if (c == 0) { return 0.0; }  return avg / c;",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  }
}
```

This appears to work, and produces the same result as the standard `avg` metric.

I'm afraid however that the part in `map_script` might be incorrect. In all the examples I've seen, this script is performing some kind of `.add` method to the state, and the summing is done in the `combine_script`.

I think this might be due to concurrency issues, which make the `+=` unsafe in the `map_script`. Is this the case? Or is my script correct?

Comment: Care you could have / by 0. I am curious, why not just use the stats aggregation?

Comment: This is just a simplified example, to explain the problem. I'm trying to do something slightly more complex actually (a weighted standard deviation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, go to the Source! On Elastic's github repo, there are a few `scripted_metric` examples.

If you check [this one](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/e9e121c9ce65bdb27dd9307657bf85298020ea8c/docs/reference/transform/examples.asciidoc#finding-suspicious-client-ips-by-using-scripted-metrics) you'll notice that they proceed in exactly the same way as you do, i.e. they do increment values directly in `map_script`.

Sad that only String and primitives types are allowed to be stored in internal state, otherwise you could have traded your double primitive with a `java.util.concurrent.atomic.DoubleAccumulator` and call `accumulate()` in `map_script` instead of `+=`.

Unless you have actually [witnessed real issues](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) that would back up your doubts, I wouldn't really worry about it at this point.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to settle the point! I'm not trying to optimize, it's just a possible concurrency issue, which would be very difficult to spot afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Some references I found.

1. Based on the documentation of [Scripted metric Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html#_scope_of_scripts):

> The scripted metric aggregation uses scripts at 4 stages of its
> execution:
>
> **init_script** Executed **prior to any collection** of documents.
>
> **map_script** Executed **once per document** collected. This is a required
> script.
>
> **combine_script** Executed **once on each shard** after document collection
> is complete.
>
> **reduce_script** Executed **once on the coordinating node** after all shards
> have returned their results.

2. Based on [Metric aggregation map context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-metric-agg-map-context.html#painless-metric-agg-map-context)

> Use this Map to add values for processing in a combine script.
> Additional values must be of the type Map, List, String or primitive.
> The same state Map is shared between all aggregated documents on a
> given shard.

3. Take a look at this [Worked Example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html#_worked_example) on how the scripts actually work on document, shard and node level.

I think your case is pretty straightforward & simple and should work fine.

However, in complex scenarios, I think its best to do only mapping in `map` context [[2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-metric-agg-map-context.html#painless-metric-agg-map-context)]  and use `combine` context which works on each shard to do the computations since the mapped state is available across all shards.

Here's [painless source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/modules/lang-painless/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/painless), if interested in digging in further.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, however I already read the documentation, and I did not really find an answer to my question: is it ok to calculate sums in map_script, or only adding to a map/array is allowed, and sums must be calculated in combine_script?

Comment: I couldn't find a concrete answer in the documentation. Interpreted based on context.